# Angular Firestore Returning User Document

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a global user service where any component can retrieve the current user's document in **Firestore** with real-time changes.

Here is my global User Service method:

```
  getUser() {
    let userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
    return this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc('users/' + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).valueChanges();
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my component's  which I import my User Service:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let user = this.userService.getUser();
  }
```

I know I need to subscribe to the `valueChanges` ...but from my component, I am getting an error.

Comment: "I am getting an error" Edit your question to include the exact error and the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Service:

```
getUser() {
    let userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc('users/' + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).get();
      }
    });
  }
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
          res => {
            let user = res.data()
          }
      );
 }
```

Comment: In my component, I get the error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Unsubscribe'...it is not allowing me to subscribe to the getUser() function. The subscribe is underlined red.

Comment: Modified the service slightly. I think the prob is that this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged isn't always true, so when you are subscribing, no observable is returned

Comment: Still no luck :/

Comment: Can you share a stackbiltz